# Issue With Darknet

Tags: opencv, makefile, darknet

The **make** command is not working , it was working before i reinstalled opencv  because it was displaying;

```
(darknet 409 error) g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed 
Video Stopped Streaming!...
```

error and now when i have reinstalled OpenCV when i am running **make** command this is what it shows and than stops;

```
$ make
chmod +x *.sh
```

Can someone please guide me I am so lost with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clean your compilation and then compile again

```
$ make clean
```

and then

```
$ make
```

Comment: Can you explain why this solves the above problem?